# Django url rewrite engine implementation

Tags: django, url-rewriting

I am looking for how to implement URL rewrite in Django which is explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine .

For example,I would like to convert

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/employer/full_detail/20/`
 to 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/employername-20.htm`

How can I implement this in Django? could suggest me a document or give an example ? Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to rewrite urls through django (really...you probably don't want to rewrite them at all) You might be looking for a redirect, or you might want to rewrite/redirect from whatever you're using to serve Django in production (nginx or Apache most likely)

Comment: I couldn't understand. So how can I achive that conversion in my example without rewriting the url ?

Comment: You directly respond to the first URL. Django doesn't need the extension.